# crop an image in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native

User can move the crop functionalities according to their needs means downward,upward,left side or rightside may be.Anyone have any idea how to crop the image in react native,I want that image for scanning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker)

Comment: Yes,I have tried that one,But i want my cropper is look like different like a scanner app,not like zoom in and zoom out functionalities

Comment: You could try to change the styling of the image-crop-picker component to your needs.

Comment: can you tell me what changes i have to do in that  image-crop-picker

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-perspective-image-cropper

https://github.com/Michaelvilleneuve/react-native-perspective-image-cropper

Comment: along with https://github.com/Michaelvilleneuve/react-native-perspective-image-cropper React-native-perspective-image-cropper

Comment: Yes,I have tried this one also,I want my scanner should be flexible in every angle so i need logic

Comment: then you can use https://scanbot.io/en/sdk.html its available for react-native as well

Answer (score 0):

You could use react-native-document-scanner-plugin for scanning purpose.